# Prove rigorously that $\inf\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I used the definition of $\inf $ to prove this. Let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Since, $0<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, $0$ is a lowerbound of $A$. 
And, by the Archimedean property, given any $\frac{1}{n} \in A$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{n}$.In other words, we have proved that any number greater than the glb is not an lower bound. Hence, we are done.

Is this rigorous enough?

Comment: The glb of an infinite set does not have to be a member of that set.

Comment: Define rigor. An alternative way of proving could be by contradiction. Assume there as some $a>0$ such that $a$ is the $inf$ of the set for all $n$. How will that lead to a contradiction?

Comment: $-1$ is also a lower bound, so is the infimum also $-1$?  (Obviously not.)  But how do you know there is or isn't a lower bound greater than $-1$?  Then how do you know there is or isn't a lower bound greater than $0$?

Comment: @EricTowers What I've proved is the contrapositive of your statement. You're stating that if a is any lowerbound for any set then a ≤ glb. And what I've proved is the contrapositive.

Comment: Which part of your proof fails to work when you replace "$0$" with "$-1$"?  I don't find that it does.  Starting with "And, by the Archimedean property ..." what you prove is that no element of $A$ is a lower bound.  (I know this because you only choose an arbitrary element of $A$, not of $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @EricTowers That was enlightening. Well, I've been using Abbott's text and he says it use "Use the Archimedean Property of R.." and I don't know how to achieve that if x in R is not positive. I'll try to fix my proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You showed that $0$ is a lower bound, and that no element of $A$ is a lower bound of $A$. You have to show that no element of $\mathbb R$ greater than $0$ is a lower bound of $A$. You might try this: let $x\in\mathbb R$ with $x>0$. By the archimidean property, there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\geq 1/x$. Now finish the argument.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea to first establish that $0$ is a lower bound for $A$, which is evident. I think a good way to proceed after this is by showing that, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $A\cap [0,\varepsilon)\neq\emptyset$. This will show that $0=\inf(A)$ by the characterisation of infimum. We can show that $A\cap [0,\varepsilon)\neq\emptyset$ by showing that $[0,\frac{1}{n})\neq\emptyset$ for any $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, which is fairly easy to argue.