# Using the Archimedian Property to prove $\inf\{{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}} = 0$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Here's what I've tried so far.

**Show $\inf{A}$ exists and is the greatest lower bound (infimum)** ($A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$)

A is trivially nonempty (for example, $n=1 \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow 1/1 = 1 \in A$)

A is bounded below: since $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

$\Rightarrow$ Let's take $\alpha=0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Since A is a strictly positive and nonzero set, $\forall x \in A$, $x \gt \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha = 0$ is a lower bound for $A$.

Let's say $x$ is an arbitrary lower bound for $A$. Assume $x \gt 0$. By AP, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx \gt 1 \Rightarrow x \gt \frac{1}{n}$ would imply that $x$ is not a lower bound of $A$ which contradicts our premise.

$$\Rightarrow x \not\gt 0 \Rightarrow 0 \geq x$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 = \inf{A}$$
$$\Rightarrow \inf\{{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}} = 0$$

Is this a valid proof or is there something that I'm missing?

This is different from the linked question because I am not only asking about the validity of my usage of the Archimedian property, but the totality of my reasoning.

Comment: $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not sufficient to show $A$ is bounded below.

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581916/archimedean-property-usage) answer your question?

Comment: That post is helpful for confirming that my reasoning is valid, but I'm moreso just asking if there are any logical leaps that I made that don't directly follow from the previous declaration.

Comment: @mrepic1123 Since $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, A is bounded below if $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall x \in A$, $x \geq \alpha$. Let's take $\alpha = 0$. Because $A$ is a strictly positive, nonzero set, $\forall x \in A$, $x \gt \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha = 0$ is a lower bound for $A \Rightarrow A$ is bounded below. Is this not correct reasoning?

Comment: @robertlewison The way you formatted your post made it seems as though the statement that $A$ is strictly positive and non-zero is separate from your justification of the fact that $A$ is bounded below

Comment: Edited to try and make my reasoning easier to follow.

Comment: It would be clearer if you removed "since $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. $\Rightarrow$". Btw, there were similar proofs in  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527036 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616952. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). [...]"

Comment: After you assume $A$ is bounded below then you proof is perfect.  As for why $A$ is bounded below ... You know... It'd be easier to read if you left off all that $A \subset \mathbb Q \subset\mathbb R$ stuff.  It's a given that $A\subset \mathbb R$ so there is no need to state it and $A\subset \mathbb Q$ is utterly irrelevant.  Simply point out (and *DO* point it out!)  as all elements of $A$ are positive the set is bounded below by $0$.